# Why is there difference in type intellisense/type inference for certain GUI controls when filtering Events

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, f#

I observed that based on the type of control VS will sometimes correctly identify the type it belongs to, but sometimes it will just stick to a somewhat general `EventArgs`.

Is this some Winforms/.Net artifact?

For example, in this case I have some tabs on a form (f1). The x will be correctly identified as `TabControlEventArgs`, and I can dot into it.

```
f1.tabControl1.Selected
    |> Event.filter (fun x -> x.TabPage.Name <> "Tab3")
    |> Event.add (fun _ -> f1.comboBox2.Enabled <- false)
```

[image]

But in the below case, x will just show `EventArgs`, and I  have to explicitly identify the property:

```
f1.my2CheckBox.CheckedChanged
    |> Event.filter (fun x ->  not f1.my2CheckBox.Checked)
    |> Event.add (fun x -> f1.comboBox2.Enabled <- false)
```

[image]

I assume this is because some controls pass more info about their events than others. Is there a specific reason for this or is this just an implementation detail, based on what some controls can do, so for example for the tabcontrol it makes sense to access its pages.

Comment: @GuyCoder that's a good idea!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this some winforms/.Net artifact?

Well it's not particularly specific to Windows Forms, in that you *could* see it anywhere... it just depends on which delegate type was used to declare the event. For example, [`TabControl.Selected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selected) is of type [`TabControlEventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontroleventhandler) which is declared as:

```cs
public delegate void TabControlEventHandler(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
```

... whereas [`CheckBox.Changed`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged) is declared as type [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler), which is declared as:

```cs
public delegate void EventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

If you do the same thing in your own code, you'll see exactly the same difference. Basically, when you declare an event you can choose how specific the event handler type is, and control authors have taken different approaches to that. For `CheckBoxChanged`, you can easily ask the checkbox for its new state, of course.